# Retrieving posts specific to subscribed users

Tags: php, cakephp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CakePHP Subscribe Users Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219037/cakephp-subscribe-users-model)

I have three models

1. User
2. Post
3. Friendship

What i want is that if USER A have subscribed to USER B and USER C, Then USER A may only be able to view posts shared by USER B and C and not others.

First, i want to know if i made proper associations.

User Model:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
      'UserFriendship' => array(
          'className' => 'User',
          'joinTable' => 'friendships',
          'foreignKey' => 'user_from',
          'associationForeignKey' => 'user_to'
        )
   );
```

Friendship Model:

```
 public $hasMany = array(
      'FriendFrom'=>array(
         'className'=>'Friendship',
         'foreignKey'=>'user_from'
      ),
      'FriendTo'=>array(
         'className'=>'Friendship',
         'foreignKey'=>'user_to'
      )
   );

public $belongsTo = array(
  'UserFrom'=>array(
     'className'=>'User',
     'foreignKey'=>'user_from'
  ),
  'UserTo'=>array(
     'className'=>'User',
     'foreignKey'=>'user_to'
  )
```

);

If the associations are correct what exactly i have to do with Post Model or Post Controller or any where else to show USER A the posts of user`s he is subscribed to?

I just need a bit of hint as i am not able to make any appropriate logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always find the easiest way to do this is: find the user ID's who are user A's friends:

```
$this->User->Friendship->find('list', array('fields'=>array('Friendship.user_to'),'conditions'=>array('Friendship.user_from'=>$this->Auth-User('id'));
```

After that, you can find all posts posted where the `Post.user_id` is `IN` your array of User ID's:

```
$this->Post->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Post.user_id'=>$friendIds));
```

Comment: What you are trying to say is that in PostsController i should do something like this 

$this->Post->Friendship->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('Friendship.user_from'=>$this->Auth-User('id'));